# YouTrack REST API: How to attach image to issue?

Tags: java, rest, attachment, youtrack

Attaching images to an issue in YouTrack, [using the REST API](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/YTD65/Attach+File+to+an+Issue), the files show up as normal attachments. I cannot view them hovering the item by mouse, instead I always have to download the files to have them displayed (*which is annoying*).

When I upload an image manually in the web UI, the image is displayed right away. What am I doing wrong, or rather how does YouTrack decide how to provide attachments to the user in web UI?

I'm using [Apache's `MultipartEntityBuilder`](http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-multipart-upload) to create the MIME body of the REST request, setting the ContentType to `ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM`. Should I set it to some sort of image MIME type when uploading?

Answer (score 2):

> setting the ContentType to ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM

YouTrack decides to let the file be previewed or downloaded based on its content type. application/octet-stream is not considered a safe one, thus, no file preview is allowed.

Use one of the following "safe" mime types depending on the image type: image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png.